# Couchbase view query not returning all matching documents

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view, couchnode

I created a view with two fields as key for the index like this **[type, time]**. When I tried to fetch the documents using the below query I was missing some of my documents in the resultset.

Javascript view I used looks something like this:

```
function(doc,meta) { 
   if(doc.name==type_1)
     emit([type_1,doc.time],doc);
   else if(doc.name==type_2) 
     emit([type_2,doc.time],doc);
 }
```

here type_1 and type_2 are document types mentioned above

Query I used:

`URL/VIEW_PATH?stale=update_after&inclusive_end=true&connection_timeout=60000&limit=10&skip=0&startkey=[type,start_time]&endkey=[type,end_time]&full_set=true`

I had one document which should be there in the result. But I didn't get any.

Am I doing something wrong here?

> Couchbase Version: 3.1.6-1904 Enterprise Edition (build-1904)

Number of documents in my bucket ~5M

Comment: Your query limits the number of documents to 10, did you get less than 10 documents?

Comment: Please don't use the `couchdb` tag for things unrelated to CouchDB

Comment: @uminder I have one document which should be there in the result. But I didn't get any. So this was not the issue for sure

Comment: Would you please post the javascript view code?

Comment: @MatthewGroves It looks something like this: 
`function(doc,meta) 
 { if(doc.name==type_1)  
     emit([type_1,doc.time],doc);
else if(doc.name==type_2) 
      emit([type_2,doc.time],doc);}`
here type_1 and type_2 are document types I mentioned in the question

Comment: Are type_1 and type_2 supposed to be strings? E.g. should it be `doc.name=="type_2"`? Also, could you post the one document that you expect to be in the result?

Comment: @MatthewGroves yes, I'm using quotes around my document type.
`{
  "name": "userJob",
  "data":SOME_VALUE,
  "time": "1576045481"
}`
This is a sample doc I'm expecting in the result